Problems with removing metadata with ExifTool
I wanted to ask you a question about a problem that occurred to me with ExifTool, since I have tried to remove the Creation tag from the image metadata, because I added it by mistake and had to delete it, but every time i try to delete it, it shows me the following message:
Warning: Tag 'Creation' is not defined
Nothing to do.

I have tried everything and I can't find anything on the internet to remove it, even if I use the classical method:
exiftool -Creation= image.png

I suspect it must be something related to a property of the image and I assume that is the cause of the error, but I will continue looking for a way to remove it without having to remove all the metadata.

This is Exiftool FAQ #3.
As the response says, there isn't a tag that exiftool knows that is called "Creation". You need to use the command in the FAQ #3 to figure out what the actual name of the tag is. You can then use that name in your original command.

In PNG files, there can be (but not always) a CreationTime tag, which may be what you're looking for.
